# SHAP for stacking classifier

Tags: classification, python, stacking, shapley-value

We are using a stacking classifier to solve a classification problem. The data feed 5 base models, the predicted probabilities of the base models feed the supervisory classifier. We would like to use SHAP to interpret the classifier as a whole.

Is it legitimate to use a kernel explainer?

Here is a minimal reproducible example - it is not the problem we are facing.

```py
import shap
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(*shap.datasets.iris(), test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

knn = sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X_train, Y_train)

svc_linear = sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)
svc_linear.fit(X_train, Y_train)

rf = sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=2, random_state=0)
stacking_model = sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier([('knn', knn), ('svc', svc_linear)], rf)
stacking_model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

shap.initjs()

explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(stacking_model.predict_proba, X_train)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test.iloc[0,:])
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value[0], shap_values[0], X_test.iloc[0,:])
```

We are aware of [this thread about SHAP for staking models](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/112#issuecomment-410074621), but there is no answer to our questio.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I meet the seem problem. And when I apply kernel explainer to my stacking model, it doesn't work.